# jQuery draggable + droppable: how to snap dropped element to dropped-on element

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have my screen divided into two `DIV`s. In the left `DIV` I have a few 50x50 pixel `DIV`s, in the right `DIV` I have an empty grid made of 80x80 `LI`s. The `DIV`s on the left are draggable, and once dropped on a `LI`, they should snap to center of that `LI`.

Sounds simple, right? I just don't know how to get this done. I tried by manipulating the dropped `DIV`'s `top` and `left` CSS properties to match those of the `LI` they're dropped into, but the `left` and `top` properties are relative to the left `DIV`.

How can I best have the dropped element snap to the center of the element it's dropped into? That's gotta be simple, right?

**Edit:** I'm using jQuery UI 1.7.2 with jQuery 1.3.2.

**Edit 2:** For whoever else has this problem, this is how I fixed it:

I used Keith's solution of removing the dragged element and placing it inside the dropped-on element in the `drop` callback of the droppable plugin:

```
function gallerySnap(droppedOn, droppedElement)
{
    $(droppedOn).html('<div class="drop_styles">'+$(droppedElement).html()+'</div>' );
    $(droppedElement).remove();
}
```

I don't the dropped element to be draggable again, but if you do, just bind draggable to it again.

For me this method also solved the problem I had when positioning the dropped elements (which would be relative to the left `DIV`) and scrolling inside the second `DIV`. (Elements would remain fixed on page, now they scroll along).

I did play with the snap options to make it look good while dragging, so thanks to karim79 for that suggestion.

I probably won't win any Awesome Code prizes with this, so if you see room for improvement, please share!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had a similar problem - I worked around it by manually removing the dragged element from its old parent and adding it to the dropped on element.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about this solution. The snap-to solution by karim79 isn't totally solving my problem so I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 75):

I found that Keith's method worked for me. Since his answer doesn't include an example implementation, I'll post mine:

```
$('.dropTarget').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});
```

or, slightly more concisely:

```
$('.dropTarget').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: IMO this should be the default behaviour of `draggable` & `droppable`.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for your post - it helped me in the right direction.  I find it a bit cleaner to set the position properties of the draggable object instead of messing with the HTML code.  This sets the position to the top left corner of the `droppable` object, but you can modify to have it centered as well.

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
   $(ui.draggable).css('top', $(this).position().top);
   $(ui.draggable).css('left', $(this).position().left);
}
```

Comment: +1 because the accepted answer will break functionality and layout in lots of cases. Especially if `revert` is used outside of the droppable area. While this is the right approach, `position()` won't do the job if the droppable element is not a sibling of the draggable. On complex websites with huge DOMs, the positioning will be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I found that when you do the drag, jQuery UI adds an inline to tell you where you dropped it. Below is a sample of the code that I used to snap it into place

```
$('.droppable').droppable({ drop: function(ev, ui) { 
    //Get Details of dragged and dropped
    var draggedclass = ui.draggable.attr('class'),
        droppedclass = 'class' + $(this).attr('name').toLowerCase();

    //update the classes so that it looks od.       
    ui.draggable.removeClass(draggedclass).addClass(droppedclass);  
    ui.draggable.removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("form li").draggable({snap:'.ui-droppable', snapMode:'inner', revert:true});
$('.drop').droppable({drop:function(ev, ui)
                           {$(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this))
                                           .css({position:'static', left:'0px', top:'0px'})
                                           .draggable('option', 'disabled', false)
                                           .css({position:'relative'});
                           }
                     }
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `div`s on the left are actually in the `li`s on the right (which you can confirm with Firebug), and if the `li`s are all in a `ul` (as they should be), try one or both of the following:

```
ul#right_div {
  text-align: center;
}

ul#right_div li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I checked with FireBug, but the dropped `DIV`s are still part of the left `DIV`, they have not moved in the HTML or the DOM tree, it seems?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure Firebug updates based on javascript events, but you may want to check me on that. I know the Web Dev toolbar has a "view generated source" option as well. Are you using JQuery UI to do this? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

based on Barry's code, what if we d like to add an option with an "x" button the element to be detached again from the new parent and be reattached to the initial?

i thought sth like this, but didn't seem to work..
to make some sort of a variable that hold initial state

```
var flag;
$('.draggable-div').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
        $(this).find('.undo').show();
    flag=$(this).parent();
    }
});


$('.draggable-div').find('.undo').click(function(i, e) {
    var $div = $(this).parent();
$($div).detach().appendTo(flag);
 }
```

sth is definately wrong but i don't know if you can get the concept...
just being able to reverse whatever you have dropped to their initial state.