# For "draggable" div tags that are NOT nested: JQuery/JavaScript div tag “containment” approach/algorithm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, html

Background: I've created an online circuit design application where .draggable() div tags are containers that contain smaller div containers and so forth.

Question: For any particular div tag I need to quickly identify if it contains other div tags (that may in turn contain other div tags).

--> Since the div tags are draggable, in the DOM they are NOT nested inside each other but I think are absolutely positioned.

So I think that a "hit testing" approach is the only way to determine containment, unless there is some "secret" routine built-in somewhere that could help with this.

I've searched JQuery and I don't see any built-in routine for this. Does anyone know of an algorithm that's quicker than O(n^2)?

Seems like I have to walk the list of div tags in an outer loop (n) and have an inner loop (another n) to compare against all other div tags and do a "containment test" (position, width, height), building a list of contained div tags. That's n-squared. Then I have to build a list of all nested div tags by concatenating contained lists. So the total would be O(n^2)+n.

There must be a better way?

Comment: Is there some critical reason the divs are not nested?

Comment: I'm using JQuery div.draggable() so that I can drag circuit component around a workspace.  I don't believe draggable() physically nests the div tags if I drag one inside another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jQuery "droppable" as well, in addition to "draggable".

This way you can know where you drop something, and can relocate the item in the DOM accordingly..

Have a look at [jQuery draggable + droppable: how to snap dropped element to dropped-on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254665/jquery-draggable-droppable-how-to-snap-dropped-element-to-dropped-on-element) (*explains how to remove the dropped element from its original place and add it to the drop target*)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.contains(DivContainer, LookForThisDiv);
```

example:

```
jQuery.contains(document.documentElement, document.body); // true
```

doc:

[$.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

**EDIT**
ok, its pretty much useless if those divs are not nested (just read that)
anyway, it's a nice utility function.