# JQuery draggable/droppable: drop div not taking ownership of dragged item

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm working on an application for my kids' summer camp which should let counselors drag a camper's name from one activity to another within a larger activity grouping.  I'm using JQuery draggable and droppable, and it's all working well, except for one thing: after I drag a an item to a different droppable container, the document is not updated.  I created a jsfiddle that shows the behavior:

https://jsfiddle.net/1sbuv82q/

To demonstrate the behavior I'm asking about, go to the Fiddle, and drag "Mattias Jabs" from Cooking to Krav Maga.  Then click Save, and check the console log: you'll see "DBG: Camper ID 4 is here!" logged for Chug ID 3, not 2, even though we moved camper 4 from 3 to 2 in the UI.

I think the fix should go somewhere here:

```
$el.sortable({
    connectWith: '.chugholder'
  });
  $el.droppable({
    accept: "ul.gallery li",
    activeClass: "ui-state-active",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover"
  });
```

I tried following some suggestions to detach from the original container, but that only caused the camper to be detached- he still did not appear in the dragged-to container (the camper icon also became unmoveable after that- I want the user to be able to move the camper as many times as they like before the they hit save).

I tried following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308290/jquery-draggable-and-droppable-between-two-containers-and-sortable), adding a "drop" function to the .droppable:

```
$el.droppable({accept: "ul.gallery li",
             activeClass: "ui-state-active",
             hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
             drop: function(event, ui) {
             var droppedOn = $(this);
             var dropped = ui.draggable;
             droppedOn.addClass("ui-state-highlight");
             $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
        }
);
```

This line is trying to detach the dragged item from its old div and then attach it to the new div:

```
$(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
```

That did move the dropped item to the new location, but the dragged item still did not register when I queried the contents of the dropped-to div tag.  Also, the dragged item could no longer be moved.  OTOH, the dragged item did disappear from the source `<div>`, so it seems like this might be the right track.

Any help would be much appreciated- thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close to the answer. The problem is with the lines you were adding:

```
// Let chug holders be droppable.                    
$('.chugholder').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.droppable({
    accept: "ul.gallery li",
    activeClass: "ui-state-active",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
         var droppedOn = $(this);
         var dropped = ui.draggable;
         droppedOn.addClass("ui-state-highlight");
         $(dropped).detach().css({top:0,left:0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
  });
```

When you get `droppedOn`, you are probably getting the `.chugholder`. You don't want to put the dropped `li` in the `div.chugholder`, you want to put it in the `ul.gallery`. Therefore just change

```
 var droppedOn = $(this);
```

to

```
 var droppedOn = $(this).find(".gallery").addBack(".gallery");
```

The `find` method finds the children that match the selector and the `addBack` method adds back the element originally dropped on if it also matches the selector. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sbuv82q/3/)

Comment: Thanks so much, bytesized - that solved my problem!  I really appreciate it!  In the words of Val Kilmer/Chris Knight from the movie Real Genius, when presented with the CalTech physics exam answers: "I didn't get you anything!" :-)

Comment: @DavidLobron No problem, glad I could help. If this answer solves your problem, you should consider accepting or upvoting it.

Comment: Just did!  Thank you again for the assistance here.