# How to drag and drop between two containers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

While running this **HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div id="container1">
            <div class="dropEL col-6">
              <p>Element 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="dropEL col-6">
              <p>Element 2</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div id="container2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this **JS**

```
var currentParent;  
$(".dropEL").draggable({
  containment: "#container2",
  grid: [ 20, 40 ],
  snap: true,
  start: function(){
    currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  }
}); 
$('#container1, #container2').droppable({
  accept:'.dropEL',
  drop: function(event,ui) {
    if (currentParent != $(this).attr('id')) {
      $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this)).removeAttr('style');
    }
    $(this).find("div").on("click", function(e){
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      if($(this).hasClass("col-6")) {
        $(this).find("p").css("background-color", "red");
        $(this).removeClass("col-6").addClass("col"); 
      } else {
        $(this).find("p").css("background-color", "green");
        $(this).removeClass("col").addClass("col-6");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I am able to drag and drop from container 1 to container 2 but i cannot drag and drop back to container 1. How could I?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yodLBy) here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308290/jquery-draggable-and-droppable-between-two-containers-and-sortable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery draggable and droppable between two containers and sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308290/jquery-draggable-and-droppable-between-two-containers-and-sortable)

Comment: @cale_b I had a look at those answer before and I couldn't make it work with mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change code as below

```
 $(".dropEL").draggable({
      containment: ".container",
      grid: [ 20, 40 ],
      snap: true,
      start: function(){
        currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
      }
    });
```

you mentioned containment as #container2 that is the root cause. 
Please find the Updated Code Pen:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqLvQB

Comment: excellent, thanks a lot, tbh i had achieved it too and I was going to add my own answer by simply removing the containment state all together, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaLWgM