# How to append <li> to <ul> using draggable and droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a tiny problem controlling where my `<li>` objects go when I use draggable and droppable from JQuery UI.

I have created this pretty elaborative fiddle to illustrate my problem: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g2oqp0h/3/)

Why doesn't the `.courseBox` go into the `.semester` `<ul>`?

The `.courseBox` should be movable back and forth and it's not only when trying to append it to the `.semester` I have this problem. It happens when trying to move the `.courseBox` back to the `.basket` as well.

I believe it could have something to do with my `moveCourse` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this by searching around a little. [jQuery draggable + droppable: how to snap dropped element to dropped-on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254665/jquery-draggable-droppable-how-to-snap-dropped-element-to-dropped-on-element)

The answer from Berry Pitman did the trick. I updated my drop-code to the following and removed the `moveCourse()` function:

```
drop: function(ev, ui) {
    var dropped = ui.draggable;
    var droppedOn = $(this);
    $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g2oqp0h/6/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from this line :

```js
function moveCourse(item, target){
  var parent = item.parent();
  var boxId = item.attr("id");
  console.log(parent.attr("id") + " contains " + boxId);
  console.log("target is: " + target.attr("id"));
  parent.find(boxId).remove(); // Here you are deleting the li element
  target.append(item); // THIS LINE
}
```

So basically, you're deleting the li element and then you re-append the li element in the target container.

P.S : It seems that the moveCourse function is useless.